# QGIS training manual 6.1.4

Tags: training

I'm following the [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/pdf/en/QGIS-2.18-QGISTrainingManual-en.pdf) and I've successfully digitised the fields, now I must do the paths. I can trace the paths but instead of it being a line, it creates a shape/area. [image: shape/area.]

What am I doing wrong? I'm also confused by the general instructions:

"Create a new line feature called routes.shp with attributes id and type."

I created a new layer called "routes" exactly like the "school_property" layer. I then entered edit mode with route layer selected and digitised the path. When the attributes box appeared for the first route, I wasn't sure what to put in the "ID and routes" box.

Comment: Please, add the link of the training manual. It's unclear what you post here

Comment: Did you select Line as the type when you created the shapefile?

Comment: I'm on polygon as per the school property layer. Ha, will it be as simple as selecting line instead of polygon?

Comment: Thanks to  lambertj and aldo_tapia. Simply put, I selected polygon instead of line. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new layer, just select **line**:

[image]